# Package app with proper keystore certificate

Tags: android, google-play, appcelerator, keystore, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to update my app in Google Developer, but receive the error:

```
Upload failed

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

[ SHA1: AF:AF:68:1E:2B:5C:99:23:4D:B9:87:F6:D6:2F:9D:5A:9A:BE:34:EC ]

and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):

[ SHA1:2A:84:1D:BC:91:68:55:B1:F3:90:47:FB:3B:56:29:21:F2:38:4A:37 ]
```

However, using keytool, the keystore file contains 2 entries, both of these certificates.

How do I package the app using the correct keystore certificate that matches so I can submit an upgrade?

Comment: You say your keystore contains both entries, but they should have unique aliases. Did you specify the correct alias when building?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same keystore file and same alias as used before. So it is always better to make a backup of the kestore file alias and password in cloud when you publish an app.